# Как в Yii2 передать два параметра action view и как нужно прописать urlManager rules для двух параметров?

Tags: php, yii2

Передать нужно два параметра id и url_alias в action view и настроить rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проще пример показать, чем объяснять.

**Пример**

Правило в конфиге `urlManager`:

```
['pattern' => 'articles/<url_alias:[A-Za-z0-9-_]+>/<id:\d+>', 'route' => 'article/info'],
```

Контроллер:

```
class ArticleController extends yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionInfo($url_alias, $id)
    {
        // Логика экшена
    }
}
```

URL-ы будут вида:

```
http://<domain>/articles/<url_alias>/<id>
```

Comment: Всё заработало, только как id запретить перебирать в ссылке или сделать уникальным или рандом что ли?

Comment: Перебирать – не запретите. Как можно запретить пользователю/боту пробовать разные URL? Никак. А вот делать уникальным или рандомным – это другой вопрос. И желательно задать его отдельно, чтобы получить развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте

Передача двух параметров:

```
public function actionView($id, $url_alias)
{ 
    // code
}
```

Пример UrlManager Rule с двумя параметрами:

```
'videos/<id:\d+>/<url_alias>' => 'video/view',
```

[Более подробно о настройке UrlManager](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-runtime-routing.html#named-parameters)

Comment: Всё заработало, только как id запретить перебирать в ссылке или сделать уникальным или рандом что ли?

Comment: Внутри самого action Вы можете проводить проверку id и в случае чего выбрасывать исключение (например NotFoundException). Сформулируйте вопрос более конкретно, я не знаю для чего используются переменные в вашем коде, поэтому затрудняюсь дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: Вообщем в конце поста выводится id test.ru/cite/post/25 ,  но мне не нужно чтобы пользователь  мог перебирать id и ссылки выводить самостоятельно. Мне нужно чтобы пользователь не смог их перебирать  в ссылке, как то нужно так что ли test.ru/cite/post/QfyrEuR_25